# Get a ValueError when converting an array of images into float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a list of images of various dimensions:

```
images = []
for direct in directory:

    img = cv2.imread(direct)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    images.append(img)
```

I intend to normalise the images therefore I should first convert the array images into float by `x = np.asarray(images).astype(np.float32)`, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-6b9623418638> in <module>
----> 1 x = np.asarray(images).astype(np.float32)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The error corresponds to the `astype(np.float32)`, how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that cv2.imread() gives an image? If you make a typo imread does not return an image. I checked this: `x = np.asarray(images).astype(np.float32)`, and that works for me.

Comment: @joostblack I checked the syntax, I found no error. It works when I convert it into numpy array but doesn't work with `astype(np.float32)`. But when I resize each image by `img = cv2.resize(img, (64, 64))` it works fine. I think the image shape needs to be of 4d something like (400, 64, 64, 3) however my point is I do not want to resize images.

Comment: The `cv2.imread` does give you a numpy array, and you code loos good to me. It looks like the problem is somewhere else.